# Creating a 3D text mesh from a 2D glyph

Tags: opengl, text

I have thought of three steps for doing this:

1. Acquire the vertex coordinates which will represent the glyph's form
2. Extrude them
3. Render

[image: text extrusion]

Can you suggest a better method? Can you give me an insight on how to do the first and the second step?

I use FreeType 2.4.10 for text managment.

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10570082/1569168).

Comment: Thanks, but a third party library would be my last resort. I would like to see how this works under the hood.

Comment: In that link is GLTT and FTGL, both using FreeType ( 1 or 2 ) and both open source, so you can see what is under the hood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, without a library, this would require quite a few steps, but it is certainly possibly.

First convert the letter to a polygon (look at the bitmap to polygon algorithms) and then that polygon to a set of triangles using a technique that supports holes in the polygon, [see this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation). You now have a flat model built out of triangles.

Now draw the models two times. Once at (0,0,0) and once at (1,0,1) (for an effect with a shear to far away-right).

You should now have something like the picture below, but you're still missing the triangles that connect the two models and make it look 3D.

[image: Picture]

Vertices A and C are parts of the triangles of the black (front) model. Vertices B and D are parts of triangles of the white (back) model. You now have to draw triangles between them for the 3D effect. Just draw a triangle from A,B,D and from A,C,D. You have now achieved the 3D-shear effect you're looking for.

**Optimizations**

You are going to draw more triangles then you need. You don't need to draw triangles between vertices which, when connected, would cut the model. You should number/sort vertices on the edge loop and only draw triangles between (M1[x], M1[x+1], M2[y]) and alternate (M2[x],M2[x+1],M1[y]). I don't know of a readily available algorithm to detect and sort these edge loops, but take a look at how you generate vertices when triangulizing your polygon, there might be a hint/implicit sorting there. It would be even better if you can sort some sort of index buffer so that you can use a trianglestrip.